# Bringing Triggered Send Name to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I need to bring Triggered Send Name (available in Journey tracking) to Data Extension - preferably send log; for the purpose of updating Sales Cloud IER object. I haven't found any field in data views connected with that name.  Are you able to help?
[image]

Comment: You'd need to use the SOAP API's TriggeredSendDefintion object or the Journey Builder Interactions REST route to get the name of the TriggeredSend that relates to the ObjectIDs/CustomerKeys of the triggered send you see in the _JourneyActivity, _Sent and _Job data views. The email name's very easy to get from the _Job data view, though. The TriggeredSendDefinition name seems like it'd have fairly limited use in CRM, though. What's the use case for having it on the Individual Email Results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to get the Triggered Send Name into a Data Extension to update the IER record in Sales Cloud as it's already in the Salesforce **et4ae5__Automated_Send__c** object. You can just add a lookup relationship to the IER object to display the **Name** field from this object. Refer to the Entity Relationship Diagram below that I've put together with the highlighted fields.

[image: Marketing Cloud Connect ERD]

Comment: Hi Eliot, thank you for your comment! Let me explain the details: what I need to bring into IER object is the Campaign Member Id. In order to do that I need to have a journey in Marketing Cloud with "Update Sales Cloud Object" activity. In this activity I need to use Merge ID for mapping (there are only other two possibilities for mapping which are not unique). As Merge ID is nowhere to be found in Marketing Cloud, I want to receive it through joining Send Log with IER object on Contact ID, Date and Triggered Send Name. Therefore I am now wondering how to get Triggered Send Name to MC...

Comment: As the Triggered Send Name is stored in the et4ae5__Automated_Send__c object, can't you just create a Synchronized DE from this custom object?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped much!

Comment: Good to hear. Please could you accept my answer for the benefit of others, if I’ve answered your question.